# Compiling Blas on ubuntu

Tags: c, lapack, blas

I'm trying to run the testblas.c example from this website:

http://www.seehuhn.de/pages/linear#installation

I installed liblapack3 and libblas-common, but I couldn't find anything for atlas in the repositories. Compiling it will result in:

```
gcc testblas.c -o testblas -lblas -lm
testblas.c:19:19: fatal error: cblas.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
compilation terminated.
```

Which basically translates to "cblas.h: file or folder could not be found"

What do I need to do to compile this program on my machine? Is there a bigger distribution (like tex-live eg.) which install all numerical or linear algebra related libraries?

Comment: you are missing `refblas3-dev`, the site you linked to even states "This contains the BLAS header file cblas.h."

Comment: There is no such file in the ubntu repositiories. In fact all the names mentioned are different in a current ubuntu installation. It seems to be outdated

Comment: Yes I would like to do the same thing on Ubuntu that is my question. The C-Code is not debian specific, so there should be a way.

Answer (score 1):

The missing package is called "libatlas-dev" in ubuntu. Installing it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such kind of "bigger distribution" for linear algebra. Normally, header files are in -dev packages (as the comment pointed out, in your case is the refblas3-dev package).
However, if you need libraries for linear algebra, I suggest you to start here: http://www.netlib.org/blas/. You can directly download and install the blas library.